# Randomly test case fails - Forked JVM exits abnormally.

Tags: java, ant, junit, jvm, hudson

I have suite of Junit tests which passes every time I run locally. I have setup a job to run the suite, hudson uses ANT to invoke the tests.This suite was passing in the hudson machine for quite some time. But from last 3 days one test fails some times (randomly). And We have not changed to code. The error is :

Error Message

```
Forked Java VM exited abnormally. Please note the time in the report does not reflect the time until the VM exit.
```

Stacktrace

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Forked Java VM exited abnormally. Please note the time in the report does not reflect the time until the VM exit.
```

I couldn't find proper answer on google. I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846329/forked-java-vm-exited-abnormally-error-from-junit-tests)

but it doesn't seem to help.

Hudson machine details :
Windows 2003 Server
Java 1.6.0.29

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Forked Java VM exited abnormally" error from junit tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846329/forked-java-vm-exited-abnormally-error-from-junit-tests), but you may want to look here: http://softwaresalariman.blogspot.com/2008/09/netbeans-junit-java-vm-exited.html

Comment: On the blog author has mentioned not to fork the new JVM but its not possible in my case. It may look duplicate but that question also is have the solution :)

Comment: Check ram usage when hudson building project.My be it hitting a java bug.

Comment: Use the 64bit version if possible. Increase heap size (MX) and PermGen size of the forked java vm.

Comment: You might want to describe the offending test itself a bit more? Any concurrency issues? Improper context propagation from other tests (e.g. shared state via a database or static class members)? Native method calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you still have access to the console log for the failed Hudson build? If the JVM is exiting 'unexpectedly' you may find a JVM bug is causing it to crash, which would not appear in the JUnit logs (which I assume is where you've got the error message/stack trace from), but probably would do in the output from Ant.

Alternatively:

- Which version of Ant are you running? I have heard of a bug pre-Ant 1.7.1 that caused `System.exit()` to be called under some circumstances.
- You may want to check that your code is not catching any exceptions that it shouldn't be (e.g. `catch Throwable`).