# Forked Java VM Exited Abnormally for random Testcase

Tags: java, junit, ant, virtual-machine, hudson

I have a set of test suites say, X, Y, Z. When I run test suite X on my development machine it runs absolutely fine. But when I run the test suites through Hudson job on some remote machine that runs the test suites X, Y, Z, the test suite X fails. The test cases inside the test suite X are failing at random i.e. if I comment out the set of failing test cases in test suite X then sometimes it runs fine or fails in some other test case.

The error I get is,

```
Test X.SRGTestSuite FAILED (crashed)
     [java] testname:  - X.random_test
     [java] message: Forked Java VM exited abnormally. Please note the time in the report does not reflect the time until the VM exit.
```

The tech stack used here is,

- Java version         = 1.6
- Ant version          = Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on June 27 2008
- Operating System     = Linux amd64
- Junit

I tried multiple solutions available on net-like,

- Setting fork = false
- Increase Max Memory
- Add Logs and trace with Showoutput, formatter, printsummary, etc.

Note that, this is not happening after any specific code change. Please suggests some ways to figure out the root cause of the problem.

Also, this similar question does not resolve my issue,
[Foked VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846329/forked-java-vm-exited-abnormally-error-from-junit-tests), in-fact the OP of this question changed the machine itself to get this resolved.

Comment: Hi @Swapnil can you add the detailed logs and commands you are using

Comment: @Gaurav I analyzed the core file generated and found that the server is crashing and not the VM explicitly, so this isolates the test framework and application code ..now trying to trim down test suites and see if this is replicable. Will update further if required.